# rgenoud package in r - warning utils not available

Tags: r, dependencies

I'm trying to install `rgenoud` package in R version 3.2.2,
It gives me a warning that `utils` and parallel dependencies are not available.

```
install.packages("rgenoud")

Installing package into ‘\\mscloud.ms.unimelb.edu.au/ckhh/windows/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Warning: dependency ‘utils’ is not available
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/rgenoud_5.7-12.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 694221 bytes (677 KB)
downloaded 677 KB
package ‘rgenoud’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

When I try to call the package it gives me a warning.

```
library("rgenoud")
```

> Error : .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'rgenoud', details:
>     call: utils::packageDescription("rgenoud", lib.loc = rgenoudLib)$Version
>     error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In utils::packageDescription("rgenoud", lib.loc = rgenoudLib) :
>     no package 'rgenoud' was found
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rgenoud’

Comment: The warning about `utils` is rather suspicious for having a broken installation. The `utils`-package _should_ be loaded automatically on R-startup.